# Was Kho Kho played during the times of Ramayana and Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

Was [Kho Kho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kho_kho) as a game played during the times of Mahabharatha or Ramayana? Are there any real references?

[This book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=S7QxypIW-KUC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=kho+kho+hanuman&source=bl&ots=w_x5FAZXLY&sig=0eDOn7vGc5BAiYYhyEdjfa8VBqE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilicbwls7UAhUgSI8KHYo5Dx84ChDoAQgnMAE#v=onepage&q=kho%20kho%20hanuman&f=false) mentions so and also [This blog](http://www.indianetzone.com/58/history_kho_kho.htm)